# gitignore does not work as expected

Tags: git

It seems that the `.gitignore` does not work, some file match the pattern defined in the file are still added to git.

And I have googled, someone said that the files which exist in the git can not be ignored.

So in my working directory, I create the `.gitignore` file, which contains this:

```
*/out/*
```

Then I run

```
git init
git add -A
```

But when I run `git status` it tell me that the files "out/xxxx.xxx" are added and to be committed.

What's the problem?

It seems that the `git init` and `git add` command does not care about the `.gitignore` file, isn't it?

Comment: It seems we have different order, mine "create .gitignore file ---> init the repo", his "init the repo --> add the .gitignore file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `out/*` instead of `*/out/*`.

`*/out/*` will ignore files with paths like `foo/out/bar`.

Comment: Even better, use `**/out/*`, which means ignore anything under an `out` directory, no matter where that directory is ([documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)). That only works with some versions of Git though (I don't remember when it was introduced), so if it doesn't work, you're stuck having to specify each `out` subdirectory, like `out/*` and `*/out/*`.